# Increasing the Y value in a YCbCr image in Python (pillow) results desaturated image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, brightness, luminance, ycbcr

I'm using the code below to convert from/to RGB/YCbCr images, which works properly when I don't do any adjustment over Y values.

```
def rgb2ycbcr(im):
    xform = np.array([[.299, .587, .114], [-.1687, -.3313, .5], [.5, -.4187, -.0813]])
    ycbcr = im.dot(xform.T)
    ycbcr[:,:,[1,2]] += 128
    return np.uint8(ycbcr)
def ycbcr2rgb(im):
    xform = np.array([[1, 0, 1.402], [1, -0.34414, -.71414], [1, 1.772, 0]])
    rgb = im.astype(np.float32)
    rgb[:,:,[1,2]] -= 128
    rgb = rgb.dot(xform.T)
    np.putmask(rgb, rgb > 255, 255)
    np.putmask(rgb, rgb < 0, 0)
    return np.uint8(rgb)
```

```
    fn = 'parrot.jpg'
    im = Image.open(fn)
    plt.imshow(im)
```

Here I want to increase the Y value by some number.

```
    yuv_img_arr = rgb2ycbcr(np.array(im))
    print(yuv_img_arr.shape)
    print(yuv_img_arr[:,:, 0])

    yuv_img_arr[:,:, 0] += 100

    print(yuv_img_arr[:,:, 0])

    rgb_img = Image.fromarray(ycbcr2rgb(yuv_img_arr))
    rgb_img.save(fn+'converted.jpg')
    plt.imshow(rgb_img)
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5TlB.jpg)
[Processed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7c3g.jpg)

How can I solve this problem? I just want to increase the brightness of this image by using Y value.

The following code works in MathLab without any problems.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
RGB=imread('parrot.jpg');
YCBCR=rgb2ycbcr(RGB);
Y=YCBCR(:,:,1);
Y=Y+100;
YCBCR(:,:,1)=Y;
RGB2 = ycbcr2rgb(YCBCR);
```

[Matlab Processed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmLQt.png)
I was expecting the image to be brighter but there are color changes.

Comment: The Y value is of type uint8. This means it "wraps around" if addition result is greater than 255. E. g. 250 + 10 = 4 (actually 260).

Comment: You are not clipping the results, so your Y values are exceeding 255.  If your arrays are byte-wide, you'll wrap around to black.  The range of valid Cr and Cb values is much smaller when Y is small.  BTW, it would be more efficient to adjust the brightness by tweaking the RGB.  You can see that adding 1 to Y effectively bumps each component by 1.